# Implementing makeSceneTransationAnimation in Android

Tags: android, animation, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I want to create transition animation for preveiwing picture like whatsapp or telegram, and i found very userful [transition](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-android-shared-element-transition-ac36952a4a4) tutorial but i get stuck to implement in my apps. I start activity with this

```
ivProfile.setOnClickListener(v -> ImagePreview.start(context, contactResponse.getProfilePic()));
```

how to implement that code above in to action click below:

```
public void animate(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ImagePreview.class);
    String transition = getString(R.string.transition);
    View start = findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this, start, transition
        );
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, i, options.toBundle());
}
```

Comment: then what is your issue?

Comment: @MohitSuthar how to send **contactResponse.getProfilePic()** from methode animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call like this, I don't think so any issue regarding this,

make sure **transition name**(is in imageview which you have to apply transition animation) declared in ImagePreview Activity.

```
ivProfile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ImagePreview.class);
        i.putExtra("IMG_URL", "YOUR_IMAGE_URL")
        String transition = getString(R.string.transition);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this, ivProfile, transition
        );
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, i, options.toBundle());
    });
```

Comment: but in ImagePreview.class i load image from url (service), so how can i load the right image from url if i did not send url to ImagePreview.class? **...ImagePreview.start(context, contactResponse.getProfilePic());**

Comment: no problem use Glide for image loading and send image pic data via intent, i am updating my ans